# Angular - How to make 2 input same value when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to use angular to my code. I have HTML code below

```
<div ng-app="pemesanan">
<div ng-controller="datapesan">
<input type="text" name="nama1" /><br />
<input type="text" name="telephone1" />
<hr />
<input type="checkbox" name="nama_same" />Same Buyer

<input type="text" name="nama2" /><br />
<input type="text" name="telephone2" />

</div>
```

I want when checkbox is checked, input nama1 value sync with nama2 value and input telephone1 value sync with telephone2 value

then when checkbox is not checked, input nama1 not sync with nama2.

Comment: I don't get what means "sync" values between nama1, and nama2.
can you explain more about the whole functionality?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about: He got a  answer in new question 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188188/angular-input1-value-input2-same-value-when-checkbox-is-checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use ng-model in the inputs and assign those model to below inputs..

---

```
<input type="text" name="nama1"  ng-model="name1"/><br />
<input type="text" name="telephone1" ng-model="telephone1"/>
<input type="text" name="nama2" placeholder={{nama2}} value={{nama2}} /><br />
<input type="text" name="telephone2" placeholder={{telephone1}} value={{telephone1}}/>
```

---

by this way you can display the same value but for change to be appear only after checking the check box,you'll have to use onclick and some implementation in controller.