# Angular - Input1 Value Input2 same value when Checkbox is checked

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i have a problem, Here my code

```
<div ng-app="pesan">
    <div ng-controller="datapesan">
        <input type="text" ng-model="nama" name="nama1" />
        <br />
        <input type="text" ng-model="telephone" name="telephone1" />
        <hr />
        <input type="checkbox" name="nama_same" ng-model="check" ng-true-value="Yes" ng-false-value="Tidak" />Same Buyer ({{check}})
        <br />
        <input type="text" ng-model="nama1"/>
        <br />
        <input type="text" ng-model="telephone1"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my controller

```
var pesan = angular.module("pesan", []);

pesan.controller("datapesan", function($scope){
    if($scope.check){
        $scope.nama1=$scope.nama;
        $scope.telephone1=$scope.telephone;
    }
});
```

I want `<input name="nama1">` has same value with `<input name="nama">` and `<input name="telephone1">` has same value with `<input name="telephone">` with condition checkbox is checked! if checkbox not checked, each input can has different value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one;

```
    var pesan = angular.module("pesan", []);

        pesan.controller("datapesan", function($scope){

          $scope.$watch('check',function(){

            if($scope.check === 'Yes'){
               $scope.nama1=$scope.nama;
                $scope.telephone1=$scope.telephone;
            } else {
                $scope.nama1='';
                $scope.telephone1='';
            }
          });


    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use $scope.$watch to keep a look on the `$scope.check` variable. Once user click the checkbox, watchCheck would be invoked. Since you have defined the `ng-true-value` as "Yes", you have to check the `checked ==== 'Yes'` when the `$scope.check` changes.

```
$scope.$watch('check', function watchCheck(checked) {
    if (checked === 'Yes') {
        $scope.nama1=$scope.nama;
        $scope.telephone1=$scope.telephone;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/G4H4YfwTKO1jmiFDFIu6?p=preview
      var pesan = angular.module("pesan", []);

```
    pesan.controller("datapesan", function($scope){

      $scope.$watch('check',function(){

        if($scope.check){
           $scope.nama1=$scope.nama;
            $scope.telephone1=$scope.telephone;
        }
      });


});
```